# Custom jquery not code not working in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script

I need to make show sub menu on click,I tried to do it by custom j query.

I have menu structure like this,

```
<ul class="vc_grid-filter vc_clearfix vc_grid-filter- vc_grid-filter-size-md vc_grid-filter-center vc_grid-filter-color-" data-vc-grid-filter="product_cat">
    <li class="vc_active vc_grid-filter-item parent"><a class="dropdown-toggle"><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-61">Product by Doctors</span></a>
        <!-- fix whitespace
                -->
    </li>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-62">GP</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-63">Paediatrics</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-64">Physician</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-65">Orthopaedic</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-66">Gynaecology</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-67">Dentists</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-68">General Surgeon</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-69">ENT</span></li>
    </ul>
    <li class="vc_active vc_grid-filter-item parent"><a class="dropdown-toggle"><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-60">Products by Category</span></a>
        <!-- fix whitespace
                -->
    </li>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-70">Anti Biotic</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-71">Anti-Inflammatory</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-72">Tonics</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-73">Anti Cold and Expectorants</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-74">Antacids and Antiulcer</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-75">Ointments</span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vc_grid-filter-item child">
        <li><span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-76">Gastro-Intestinal</span></li>
    </ul>
    <li class="vc_grid-filter-item"><a class="dropdown-toggle"><span data-vc-grid-filter-value="*">Complete Product List</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

in js folder of the theme, I created the jquery file named drop.js.Here is the code

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j(".child").hide();
    $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){

        $("ul",this).toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

and in function.php file code I have added

//this goes in functions.php near the top

```
function my_scripts_method() {
// register your script location, dependencies and version
    wp_register_script( 'custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/drop.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
// enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Can u please check this code and let me know where I am wrong.It is not working.
Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors on your page?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your html structure. It should be

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Somwthing</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually its a snap of html code,original code is in basic filter. I added in question,plz check the code.